# How do I display a user's clipboard contents in an UILabel?

Tags: ios

How do I display the contents of the users clipboard in an UILabel?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line would do.

UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];

lbl.text = pasteBoard.string;

Comment: thanks! this is a good article about this stuff: http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-3-copy-paste-with-uipasteboard/